What Integer Polynomials satisfy $P(n)=P(-n-1)$?
I'm trying to find the integer polynomials that satisfy $P(n)=P(−n−1)$.
I suspect the only such polynomials can be written as:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i (x(x+1))^i$$
But I'm not sure how to show these are the only ones.
I also had another idea of defining $Q(x)=P(x-\frac{1}{2})$ so that $Q$ is even, but the fact that we need integer coefficients for $P$ complicates this approach.

You can rewrite that conjecture as $Q(x(x+1))$ for $Q$ an integer polynomial.

And you probably mean $a_i(x(x+1))^i.$

From How to ask a good question: Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

I assume this is related to an investigation of the symmetry of Faulhaber polynomials, generalizing Nicomachus's Theorem.

Let $P_1(x)=P(x)-P(0).$ Then $P_1(0)=P_1(-1)=0,$ so $P_1(x)$ is divisible by $x(x+1).$ Let $P_2(x)=\frac{P(x)-P(0)}{x(x+1)}.$ Then $P_2$ is an integer polynomial with $P_2(n)=P_2(-n-1)$ and $\deg(P_2)=\deg(P)-2.$
Then proceed by induction on the degree of $P.$

Thanks. Is there a general rule for this? i.e. solving P(x)=P(Q(x)) where Q(x) is some fixed polynomial?

No idea. That's a  muchbigger question. It's certainly not possible with $P$ not constant and $\deg Q,$ since the $P(Q(x))-P(x)$ is a zero for all $n,$ which is not possible. There also isn't a case when $Q(x)=x+1$ and $P$ is non-constant. You probably need $Q$ linear, and $Q(Q(x))=x,$ just as a guess. This means $Q(x)=a-x$ or $Q(x)=x.$

Consider the linear operator $T$ defined by:
$$(TP)(x) = P(-x - 1)$$
This operator is an involution (since $T^2 = \text{id}$), and we're seeking its fixed points.
Note that:
$$T(x(x+1)) = (-x-1)(-x) = x(x+1)$$
This means every power $[x(x+1)]^k$ is also fixed by $T$. Within the vector space $\mathcal{V}_d$ of polynomials of degree at most $d$, the dimension is $d+1$, and $T$ partitions $\mathcal{V}_d$ into a direct sum of $+1$ and $-1$ eigenspaces. The set:
$$\{1, x(x+1), [x(x+1)]^2, \ldots, [x(x+1)]^{\lfloor d/2\rfloor}\}$$
provides linearly independent elements of the $+1$-eigenspace. By dimension counting (since $T$ is an involution), this must be the entire $+1$-eigenspace.
Since $x(x+1)$ has integer coefficients, any polynomial in $x(x+1)$ with integer coefficients will itself be in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Therefore, your conjectured form captures exactly the integer polynomials fixed by $T$.
Your second approach via:
$$Q(x)=P(x-\frac{1}{2})$$
actually provides another perspective on why this works: The fixed polynomials must be even around $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, meaning $Q$ is even. Since $Q$ is even, it's a polynomial in:
$$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 = x(x+1)-\frac{1}{4}$$
The integrality condition then forces us to use $x(x+1)$ as our basic building block rather than $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
